# How can I use an external SSD instead of the built in HDD on a Mac Mini Late 2014?

Tags: startup, ssd, external-disk, mac-mini, hdd

I want to clone the HDD on a late 2014 Mac Mini onto a Samsung T5 or T7 portable SSD, and use that drive as the boot drive. Is that possible, and if so, how would I even start going about such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most common utilities for this are [Bombich Software's Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/), and [ShirtPocket's SuperDuper](https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html).  Both will allow you to create a bootable clone of your current OS on an external volume; then at next startup, hold down the Option key and choose the external volume.

Note that model Mac mini only supports USB 3.0, so while it'll be faster than the internal drive, you won't get the full performance from a Samsung SSD that supports USB 3.1 or greater.

Comment: Thanks. I understand from your answer that there is no built in cloning software by Apple. Is that true?

Comment: While macOS ships with Disk Utility as well as the typical *BSD tools like `dd` you'll have a much easier time using a 3rd party utility like CCC.

Comment: Searching around it looks like Disk Utility Restore can clone as well. Thanks again.

Comment: It can, but CCC and SD have a lot more functionality built into them to make it easier.  Disk utility is just not suitable for cloning a booted macOS system.